# Am fetching data using an APIs in flutter and some images are null

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

Am fetching data using an APIs in flutter and some images are null, how can i show a default images for the null images that is returned from the APIs

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify this in your class.fromJson constructor. Here's an example:

```
class ImageModel {
  final String id;
  final Image? image;
  
  ImageModel({
    required this.id,
    this.image,
  });

  factory ImageModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) =>
      ImageModel(
        id: parsedJson['_id'] as String,
        image: parsedJson['image'] == null
          ? Image.asset(...) //Specify your default image here
          : parsedJson['image'] as Image,
      );
```

Hope this answers your question... Let me know if you have any problems.